# How do I teach perks?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

According to the [Dead by Daylight manual](http://www.deadbydaylight.com/manual/survivors/#profiles), you can teach character-specific perks to your other playable characters.

How do you that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At level 30 you will have a chance to get a teachable perk in the bloodweb. When you learn that perk you will have the chance to find the same perk in the other characters bloodwebs.

At the site below you will see some more information.

http://deadbydaylight.gamepedia.com/Unique_Perks

Answer (score 1):

Teaching perks has recently changed in patch 6.1.0. Now, instead of reaching a specified level for sharing teachable perks, you need to prestige a character. Once prestiged, that killer's/survivor's perks will be available to all other killers/survivors at tier one. You can then find those perks in other character's bloodwebs and upgrade them from there. Alternatively, if you prestige the same character two and three times, their perks will be available at tier two and three (respectively) for everyone else.